# Balmer alpha, beta line intensity

Tags: atomic-physics, thermal-radiation, photon-emission

In different temperature environments, the intensity of the Balmer line is determined by the [Saha equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation) and the [Boltzmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation). What I'm curious about is as follows. How can we measure the intensity of alpha and beta lines at the same temperature?